# Cálculo de horas paradas?

Tags: php

Preciso realizar um cálculo que me retorne a quantidade de horas que uma máquina ficou parada, em meu banco de dados tenho dois campo `data/minutos`, que são de **data parada** e **data retorno**, os mesmos estão no seguinte formato:

```
$dataParada = '201704120850' ;
$dataRetorno = '201704120955';
```

Até aí consigo fazer o cálculo com a seguinte função:

```
$dataParada = '201704120850';
$dataRetorno = '201704120955';  

$datatime1 = new DateTime($dataParada);
$datatime2 = new DateTime($dataRetorno);


$data1  = $datatime1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data2  = $datatime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  

$data1 = strtotime($data1);
$data2 = strtotime($data2);

$nHoras   = ($data2 - $data1) / 3600;
$nMinutos = (($data2 - $data1) % 3600) / 60;
$total = sprintf('%02d:%02d', $nHoras , $nMinutos);

echo $total;
```

O problema agora é que preciso levar em consideração apenas o horário de funcionamento das máquinas que seria das **07:30** até **12:00** e das **13:30** às **17:48**, e desconsiderar os **sábados**, **domingos** e **feriados**.

Comment: No caso, você precisa descontar de `$total` o tempo referente a finais de semana, feriados e horários *não-comerciais*?

Comment: Isso, preciso descontar do total, ou calcular as horas úteis antes.